# How do I make a program that queries/tests a website?

Tags: html, web, connection

I'm trying to make a program that can find out exactly when a given class at my university has an open spot -- basically I want to be able to find out when a certain number on a website isn't 0.  Then I want to be able to sign up for that class instantly.

I'm new to this kind of programming, I just have some experience in Java, html/css, javascript, and php/mysql.  I'm kind of unsure where I'd begin with a task like this, but I definitely want to try.  Any links or starting off points would be really appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: a firefox/greasemonkey userscript could easily do the task while keeping you within your existing skillset.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't have a server that can constantly check whether the class is open for you, your best bet will probably be a simple desktop program that downloads the webpage given a URL address every few minutes or so.

You also need to observe the HTML of that webpage and let your program know a way to tell if a class is open (e.g. keywords, change in page size, etc). For example, if the page contains a section like `<td>N/A</td>` that will change to `<td>Open</td>` when there's a spot, you need to let your program know that.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your university doesn't offer any kind of API. So probably you're going to have to do some kind of screen scraping, i.e. write a program that can look through an HTML page and check the values that you're interested in.

There are good open-source libraries for screen scraping in both Python (e.g. [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)) and Ruby ([Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org)). There are probably good screen scraping libraries in other languages, but I don't know much about them. Here is an article about screen scraping [in PHP](http://www.bradino.com/php/screen-scraping/), since you say you know PHP.

You could fetch the value of the webpage using, for example

- [curl](http://linux.die.net/man/1/curl) from a shell script.
- [Net::HTTP](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/index.html) library in Ruby.
- [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) library in PHP.
- [urlopen](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html) in Python.

Once you have fetched the page, and determined whether there is a spot open in the course, then you need to figure out what request you need to send to the University server to sign yourself up for the course.

You might be able to do this just by submitting a GET request with the right URL parameters set, but probably you'll have to submit some kind of POST request.  Luckily, all the tools I mentioned above will let you submit post requests.